# mysql sum columns across tables and group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, multiple-columns

Need to sum different columns across multiple tables and then group by a different column.

As part of this, tried the following to sum a single column across different tables.

```
SELECT SUM(t.Qty) AS total_qty
    FROM (SELECT Qty FROM MC
          UNION ALL
          SELECT Qty FROM Amex) t
```

But I need to find the following

(sum(t1.ATT) + sum(t2.ATT) + sum(t3.ATT) + sum(t4.ATT)) -

(sum(t1.RE_ORG) + sum(t2.RE_ORG) + sum(t3.RE_ORG) + sum(t4.RE_ORG) ) AND Group by BSM or Date, Hour

Not sure how to proceed further.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Different tables: t1, t2, t3, t4

```
mysql> show create table t1\G
*************************** 1. row *************************
       Table: t1
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `BSM` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Hour` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `BSC` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `BTS` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `SECTOR` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `BAND` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `FA` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `ASSGN_BAND` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `ATT` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `RE_ORG` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `OVD_CMP` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `OVD_BCP` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `A1_OOS` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `CMP_MSC` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `BS_REL1` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `MSC_REL1` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `MOB_REL1` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `ASR` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `ATP_UNA` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `CMP_ATP` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `CE_UNA` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `WALSH_UNA` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `TCH_OVP` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `SYN_TO` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `BCP_CEP` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `CMP_BCP` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOT_ACQ` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `MS_ATP1` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `MS_ATP2` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `SO_REJ` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `REV_NO_FRM_FROM_CEP2` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `FWD_NO_FRM_FROM_ATP2` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `BAD_FRM2` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `BS_REL2` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `MSC_REL2` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `MOB_REL2` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `ASC1` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `ASC2` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `REV_NO_FRM_FROM_CEP3` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `FWD_NO_FRM_FROM_ATP3` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `FWD_NO_FRM_FROM_MGW3` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `BAD_FRM3` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `BS_REL3` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `MSC_REL3` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `MOB_REL3` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `ANS` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `REV_NO_FRM_FROM_CEP4` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `FWD_NO_FRM_FROM_ATP4` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `FWD_NO_FRM_FROM_MGW4` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `BAD_FRM4` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `BS_REL4` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `MSC_REL4` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `MOB_REL4` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `AVG_ANS` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `AVG_CPL` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `AVG_DRP` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `AVG_TRF` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `AVG_HLD` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `AVG_DLY` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `LINK_UNA` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `BSM` (`BSM`),
  KEY `ATT` (`ATT`),
  KEY `Date` (`Date`),
  KEY `Hour` (`Hour`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=349625 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT BSM, SUM(t.ATT) - SUM(t.RE_ORG)
FROM (SELECT BSM, `DATE`, `HOUR`, ATT, RE_ORG FROM t1 union all
      SELECT BSM, `DATE`, `HOUR`, ATT, RE_ORG FROM t2 union all
      SELECT BSM, `DATE`, `HOUR`, ATT, RE_ORG FROM t3 union all
      SELECT BSM, `DATE`, `HOUR`, ATT, RE_ORG FROM t4
     ) t
GROUP BY BSM;
```

Comment: Yes...Perfect! But I also need per BSM or per Date/Hour..say like Hour='15:15:00'

Comment: @Siva . . . You can use the same subquery and just group by the fields you need to aggregate by.